# Split gzip file by file count

Tags: python, linux, split, tar, gzip

I've got a large tar.gz file that contains millions of xml files.

`split` command in linux can split by number of bites / lines, but cannot split by number of *files*. I would like to for instance split the gzip file by say 300k files in each output sub-gzip. Is there a utility to achieve this?

My ultimate goal is to process the tar.gz in Python and I need to split to the file into smaller chunks preserving the files. Splitting will allow to process them in parallel.

Comment: Gzip doesn't keep track of file boundaries. Are you sure it's not `.tar.gz`?

Comment: @Barmar to your first question: you are right, it is `.tar.gz`. To your second point - totally agree. I have however implemented a Python code to solve the problem.

Comment: You should correct the question to say what you really meant.

Comment: @Barmar thanks, I have updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `split` does not support splitting by count of files, I implemented a Python utility:

```
import tarfile
import glob
import os
import shutil 

def make_a_split(input_dir, split_num):
    print("split {}".format(split_num))
    tar_output = tarfile.open("split_" + str(split_num) + ".tar.gz", "w:gz")
    for file_name in glob.glob(os.path.join(input_dir, "*")):
        #print("  Adding %s..." % file_name)
        tar_output.add(file_name, os.path.basename(file_name))
    tar_output.close()
    shutil.rmtree(tmp_output_dir)
    print("split {} done".format(split_num))

count_per_split = 300000
split = 1

tmp_output_dir = "tmp/"

tar = tarfile.open('your.tar.gz')

for idx, tarinfo in enumerate(tar):
    tar.extract(tarinfo, tmp_output_dir)
    if idx > 0 and idx % count_per_split == 0:
       make_a_split(tmp_output_dir, split)
       split += 1
tar.close()
# did we not remove the temp dir? It means we have seen less than count_per_split and need
# to make a split
if os.path.exists(tmp_output_dir):
   make_a_split(tmp_output_dir, split)
```